# CSS hover effect doesn't work over picture

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the border on my button to appear, it works perfectly with solid background colors but not with a image . You can see the border when clicking on the button but not when mouse over it.

I just want the border to be visible.

```css
<html lang="en">    <head>
  
<style>
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {

{ background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/05/15/07/concrete-1646788_960_720.jpg") }

}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: color 0.5s, transform 0.2s, background-color 0.2s;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 23px 33px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}
button:active {
  transform: translateY(3px);
}
button::after, button::before {
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.shrink-border {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #1b1b20;
}
.shrink-border:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #E3BD1C;
}
.shrink-border::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #1b1b20;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, border 0.3s;
}
.shrink-border:hover::before {
  opacity: 0;
}
.shrink-border::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 3px solid #E3BD1C;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: scaleX(1.1) scaleY(1.3);
  transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
}
.shrink-border:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
}

.material-bubble {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #EEC02C;
  border: 3px solid #EEC02C;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.material-bubble:hover {
  color: #EEC02C;
}
.material-bubble::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #EEC02C;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, border 0.3s;
}
.material-bubble:hover::before {
  opacity: 0;
}
.material-bubble::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #EEC02C;
  border-color: #EEC02C;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-10px, -70px) scale(0.1);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, background-color 0.3s;
}
.material-bubble:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform-origin: 100px 100px;
  transform: scale(1) translate(-10px, -70px);
}
</style>
  
</head>

<body translate="no">
  <div class="container">
  <div>
<div style="background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/05/15/07/concrete-1646788_960_720.jpg');">
<a href="https://sites.google.com/u/0/d/1qexyDxBEpBgUx3IVqODoqfLs59AG0eV1/p/1SsjI8NaKooq171w4dA5LW0NvxKX9ACkG/preview?authuser=0">  
    <button class="shrink-border">Make an Appointment</button>
</a>

    </a>
  </div>
 </div>
  
</body></html>
```

Comment: Adjust the z-index of the element.

Comment: An observation rather than solution to the problem as stated: your HTML is not legal, it has a button inside an a element which is not allowed. Also there is a spurious closing curly bracket in the CSS for body - did you want the background image on the body or on the div element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Just add a z-index to your border:

```
.shrink-border {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #1b1b20;
  z-index: 0; /* <--- Add this */
}
```

**Full working Demo:**

```html
<html lang="en">    <head>
  
<style>
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {

{ background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/05/15/07/concrete-1646788_960_720.jpg") }

}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: color 0.5s, transform 0.2s, background-color 0.2s;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 23px 33px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}
button:active {
  transform: translateY(3px);
}
button::after, button::before {
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.shrink-border {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #1b1b20;
  z-index: 0; /* <--- Add this */
}
.shrink-border:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #E3BD1C;
}
.shrink-border::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #1b1b20;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, border 0.3s;
}
.shrink-border:hover::before {
  opacity: 0;
}
.shrink-border::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 3px solid #E3BD1C;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: scaleX(1.1) scaleY(1.3);
  transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
}
.shrink-border:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
}

.material-bubble {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #EEC02C;
  border: 3px solid #EEC02C;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.material-bubble:hover {
  color: #EEC02C;
  z-index: -1;
}
.material-bubble::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #EEC02C;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, border 0.3s;
}
.material-bubble:hover::before {
  opacity: 0;
}
.material-bubble::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #EEC02C;
  border-color: #EEC02C;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-10px, -70px) scale(0.1);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s, background-color 0.3s;
}
.material-bubble:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform-origin: 100px 100px;
  transform: scale(1) translate(-10px, -70px);
}
</style>
  
</head>

<body translate="no">
  <div class="container">
  <div>
<div style="background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/05/15/07/concrete-1646788_960_720.jpg');">
<a href="https://sites.google.com/u/0/d/1qexyDxBEpBgUx3IVqODoqfLs59AG0eV1/p/1SsjI8NaKooq171w4dA5LW0NvxKX9ACkG/preview?authuser=0">  
    <button class="shrink-border">Make an Appointment</button>
</a>

    </a>
  </div>
 </div>
  
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thnks a bunch, I very much appreciate it, and just one more question. How can I make that button to load the link in the same tab?

Comment: Check if you have a `target="_blank"` at your link. This will make your link open a new tab. Or using a location API.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace

Comment: I'm truly sorry, I don't know a lot about programming websites, I'm just helping someone create a google site, I'm not sure what target="_blank" is or how to use it.

Comment: Don't be sorry, mate. We are here to help. I think your given code already open the link in the same tab?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
.shrink-border:hover {
 transform: translateY(3px);
}
```